# Use Visual Studio 2022 to debug linux exe, why would MaxSpeed suppress disassembly view?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2022, disassembly

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, v17.6.2(current latest release) to build and debug an executable running on Ubuntu Linux 22.04.

I find that when I enable `<Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>` in .vcxproj, the Disassembly view says **No disassembly available**. Why is it so? Anything I can tweak to make the assembly code displayed?

Some screenshot below.

With `<Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>` (`-O0`), disassembly shows (almost) correctly. I said "almost" because there is an apparent bug: the `leave` instruction line is erroneously displayed twice.

[image: VS2022+Linux, -O0]

With `<Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>` (`-O2`), disassembly view shows nothing.

[image: VS2022+Linux, -O2]

I checked the g++ command-line as reported by VSIDE output-pane. `<Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>`'s compile-command is:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
-c -x c++
/home/chj2/projects/excptest4/excptest4.cpp
-I /home/chj2/projects/excptest4
-g2 -gdwarf-2 -o
"/home/chj2/projects/excptest4/obj.linux/x64/Debug-remote-gcc/excptest4.o"
-Wall -Wswitch
-W"no-deprecated-declarations"
-W"empty-body"
-Wconversion
-W"return-type"
-Wparentheses
-W"no-format"
-Wuninitialized
-W"unreachable-code"
-W"unused-function"
-W"unused-value"
-W"unused-variable"
-O0
-fno-strict-aliasing
-fno-omit-frame-pointer
-D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE
-fthreadsafe-statics
-fexceptions -frtti
-std=c++14
```

With `<Optimization>MaxSpeed</Optimization>`, only `-O0` becomes `-O2`, everything else remains the same.

The linker command remains exactly the same, as this:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
-o
"/home/chj2/projects/excptest4/bin.linux/x64/Debug-remote-gcc/excptest4.out"
-Wl,--no-undefined
-Wl,-z,relro
-Wl,-z,now
-Wl,-z,noexecstack
"/home/chj2/projects/excptest4/obj.linux/x64/Debug-remote-gcc/excptest4.o"
"/home/chj2/projects/excptest4/obj.linux/x64/Debug-remote-gcc/mybar.o"
-lpthread
```

The .vcxproj is [here](https://github.com/chjfth/trivials/blob/master/cpp/202306-excptest/excptest4/excptest4.vcxproj), and a small note: you need to have `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++` command on your target Linux machine, or, change each occurrence of `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++` to `g++` inside the .vcxproj .

Comment: Max speed almost certainly omits debug symbols. Which is how the debugger provides disassembly. Try `-Og` and [see also](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html).